# Return Dictionary value if key substring exist

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, substring

I want to return the value from a dictionary if the key contains a string which half matches string lookup.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _ipAddressesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
       {"ip.qwer4.abc5.somename", "6x.x.00.xx"},
       {"ip.qwer3.abc1.somename", "6x.3.xx.xx"},
}
```

Forexample,

I have a string "abc1.somename", I am building up the logic as below - *which doesn't work at the moment* - to get me the **value** given key name contains that substring. I expect to get "6x.3.xx.xx" back.

```
public string LookUpPeerIp(string deviceName)
{
    var value = _ipAddressesDictionary.Keys.Contains(deviceName);

    return value.ToString();
}
```

Edit:

Sorry guys, forget to mention the string that is passed in to do a look up ***doesn't exactly match*** either. It has a .co.uk appended to it :(

So it will be abc1.somename.co.uk but the dictionary has ip.qwer3.abc1.somename without the **.co.uk**

Comment: What should it return if there are multiple keys in the dictionary containing the substring, eg `"ip.qwer"` from your example?

Comment: What if 2 keys contain your deviceName?

Comment: @JamesThorpe That won't ever be the case for what the look up string is.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos hopefully wont be the case, if so return First()

Comment: Ok - but I like how you've gone from _"won't ever"_ to _"hopefully wont"_ in the space of 1 comment :)  Who knows what the future holds...!

Comment: what kind of substring you have? is it only this part `abc5.somename`? or can be any substring like `ip.qwer4.abc5`? i think the solution close to `O(1)` is possible if the substring is always taken from one part... if you generate hash of half of string ( for example only `ip.qwer4` part )and make your own comparer.

Comment: See my updated answer Below. Online sample is updated too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this online https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6E1wR

This will cutting right dots - My answer:

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("--first");
Console.WriteLine(LookupByPrefix("abc1.somename.co.uk"));
Console.WriteLine("--many");
string[] many = LookupByPrefixMany("abc1.somename.co.uk");
foreach(string ip in many)
    Console.WriteLine(ip);
```

For single result:

```
public string LookupByPrefix(string domainName)
{
    string[] dotDomains = domainName.Split('.');

    for(int matchCount = dotDomains.Length; matchCount > 0; matchCount--)
    {
        string[] ret = LookUpPeerIpMany(string.Join(".", dotDomains.Take(matchCount)));
        if(ret != null && ret.Length > 0) return ret.SingleOrDefault();
    }

    return null;
}
```

For multiple results:

```
public string[] LookupByPrefixMany(string domainName)
{
    string[] dotDomains = domainName.Split('.');

    for(int matchCount = dotDomains.Length; matchCount > 0; matchCount--)
    {
        string[] ret = LookUpPeerIpMany(string.Join(".", dotDomains.Take(matchCount)));
        if(ret != null && ret.Length > 0) return ret;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Dependency:

```
public string[] LookUpPeerIpMany(string deviceName)
{
    return _ipAddressesDictionary
           .Where(q=>q.Key.Contains(deviceName)).Select(q=>q.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Happy to help you!

Comment: the string lookup does't exactly match. Please look at the edits to my original question. Thanks

Comment: I Have the Answer! See now! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
public string LookUpPeerIp(string deviceName)
{
    var keySubstringMatch = _ipAddressesDictionary.Keys
        .FirstOrDefault(key => key.Contains(deviceName));
    if(keySubstringMatch == null)
        return null;
    else
        return _ipAddressesDictionary[keySubstringMatch];
}
```

maybe multiple matches are possible, then this would be a good approach:

```
public IEnumerable<string> LookUpPeerIp(string deviceName)
{
    var keySubstringMatch = _ipAddressesDictionary.Keys
        .Where(key => key.Contains(deviceName));
    foreach (string key in keySubstringMatch)
        yield return _ipAddressesDictionary[key];
}
```

Then you can process all matches, for example:

```
string allMatching = String.Join(",", LookUpPeerIp("abc1.somename"));
```

Comment: Great idea, but I just realised - to add to the complexity - the string lookup does't exactly match. Please look at the edits to my original question. Thanks

Comment: @user1781232 your edit completely changed the question! you should`ve said said that first. you would better ask another question. but remember to state any important things because solutions can change besed on these things.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
string partial = "abc5";
string value= _ipAddressesDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Contains(partial)).Value;
```

Comment: I just realised - to add to the complexity - the string lookup does't exactly match. Please look at the edits to my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all the values (or the first value) for a key that contains part of a string, you have no other way other than iterate over all the keys and return the one that suits your needs. That would be O(N) in complexity.

If instead of a contains you can live with a begins with, then a dictionary is not a good choice. You will get better performance with a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). There is no built in implementation of a Trie in the framework, but there are a couple of open source implementations available out there.

Answer (score 0):

First search for an exact match and then for a partial match.then use a regular expression

```
public string LookUpPeerIp(string deviceName)
{
        string value = null;
        _ipAddressesDictionary.TryGetValue(deviceName, out value);
        if (value != null)
            return value;

        var keyPair = _ipAddressesDictionary.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key.Contains(value));

        if (keyPair != null)
            return keyPair.Value;

        string pattern = @"your pattern";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        keyPair = _ipAddressesDictionary.FirstOrDefault(k => rgx.IsMatch(k.Key));
        return keyPair != null ? keyPair.Value : null;
  }
```

More on regular expression here
https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=4z1XVv-oMsGsPMagotAG#q=c%23+regular+expressions

Comment: Great idea, but I just realised - to add to the complexity - the string lookup does't exactly match. Please look at the edits to my original question. Thanks

Comment: If you don't have an exact or a partial match you can use regular expressions